# How can I prove the existence of two values in a given domain Mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous and differentiable on $(0,1)$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. There is a $c$ in $(0,1)$ such that $f(c) = kc$, where $k$ is a positive constant.

Show that there exists $a$ and $b$ in $(0,1)$ such that $cf'(a) +(1-c)f'(b)=-1$.

Comment: Is the $c$ in the second question same as that of the $c$ in the first question?

Comment: Yes. The c satisfies f(c)=kc.

Comment: Should the domain contain $0$ and $1$ as well?

Comment: Oops sorry, the domain should include 0 and 1.

Comment: **Hints:**

For the first part of the question, prove the following theorems,

1. Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then $f([0,1])$ is a closed interval.

2. Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. There exists a point $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=c$.

3. Apply @Asemismaiel's technique to complete the rest of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Subdivide the interval $[0,1]$ into two intervals; $[0,c]$ and $[c,1]$ then use the mean value theorem for each interval separately, then derive the desired equation.(It's easy)

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a given, The existence of such a $c$ is not always true. For consider $f(x) = x$ and $k = 100$ then $f(x) \neq kx$ for any $x$.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Actually you need to prove the existence of both $k$ and $c$ in the first question.

Comment: Well, I don't think you should because there exists infinitely many such k and c but if you insist: by the intermediate value theorem there exists a $c$ such that $f(c)=\frac{1}{2} = \frac{c}{2c} = kc$ where $k =\frac{1}{2c} $ and this works for every value between 0 and 1, not just $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I don't understand how do you conclude that "there exists infinitely many such $k$ and $c$", can you outline a proof of this assertion? Also note that (as is generally understood by the term "constant") the choice of $k$ in the problem shouldn't depend upon $c$ as is the case with your last comment.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x$, for any $k>0$(k is fixed), and every $c>0$, $f(c)=c\neq kc$.(counterexample) So the statement is not true in general.
If you're asking to find values of k and c, possible depending on one another, then my argument still works by if $\frac{1}{2}$ is replaced by by any number between zero and one(the values of f at 1 and 0, respectively.) and shows there are infinitely many such k and c.

Comment: The full assertion of the first part of the problem (as I see) is: "Let $f$ be continuous and differentiable (the domain and codomain needs to be specified for the sake of completeness but for the time being I am leaving this part as is in the main post) on $(0,1)$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Prove that **there exists** $c\in (0,1)$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(c)=kc$."

Comment: As I said in my second comment under your answer, $k$ shouldn't be dependent on $c$. The point is not that **for all** $k\in \mathbb{R}^+$ we have $f(c)=kc$ but simply that **there exists** such a $k\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and in your example $f(x)=x$ we take $k=1$.

Comment: In the case of $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x=0\\0,&x=1\\x,&x\in(0,1)\end{cases}$$ then the statement $\forall c\in(0,1)\implies f(c)=kc,k\in\mathbb R^+$ is true.  It needn't be true for all $k\in\mathbb R^+$, you just need to show there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f(c)=kc$ and $k\in\mathbb R^+$, which is true since $f(c)=c$ and $1\in\mathbb R^+$.  In fact, this example has a property stronger than what the question asks.  As @user170039 mentions, you only need to prove that it holds true for at least one $c\in(0,1)$, whereas this example holds true for all $c\in(0,1)$.